# Breaking nicely into an additional div without using extensive javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="PlanViewControls" class="ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" >
    <div id="Level1Controls">
        <div class="separated">
            <div id="PlanViewZoomSlider"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="separator">|</div>
        <div class="separated">
            <label>
                Rack Info: 
                <select id="RackInfoSelect">
                    <option value="Name">Name</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="separator">|</div>
        <div class="separated marginedTop">
            <label>
                Enable Auto-Refresh:
                <input id="PlanViewRefreshCheckbox" name="Enable Auto-Refresh" value="value" type="checkbox" />
            </label>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div id="Level2Controls">
        <div class="separated">
            <label>
                Levels To Display:
                <select id="LevelSelect">
                    <option value="All">All</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="separator">|</div>
        <div class="separated marginedTop">
            <a id="ExportPlanView" href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" title="Export the plan view as a pdf.">
                <span class="cs-icon cs-icon-edit-search-results" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;"></span>
                <label id="ExportLabel">Export</label>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (w/ latest jQueryUI for major styling)

```
#RightPaneContent
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#PlanViewControls
{
    display: none;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#PlanViewControls > div
{
    min-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.component-slider
{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 5px; 
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#PlanViewControls label
{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
    float: left;
}

#PlanViewControls input 
{    
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
}

#PlanViewControls div.separator
{
    padding-top: 4px;
}

.marginedTop
{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#ExportLabel
{
    padding-top: 1px;
}

#PlanViewControls
{
    min-width: 700px;
}

#ExportLabel:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#PlanViewControlsOverlay
{
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10001;
}
```

I am really unhappy with this solution because on wide displays the second level of controls looks unnatural -- there is enough space to hold them all in one level.

The solution I currently have in my head consists of:

- Measure the available width of the space I would like to take up.
- Measure the width of each control I have.
- Place as many controls as I can on the first line.
- Append a second level if I run out of space.

Obviously it doesn't make sense to collapse to just 1 item per row -- I would be specifiying a min-width for my first level controls.

Is this the proper way to go about doing this? Or is there an easy way to express this using CSS/HTML?

Just as a visual helper I've attached below what my page looks like on a landscape monitor vs a portrait monitor.

[image]

Comment: You've forgotten the css code.

Comment: I edited in the relevant CSS, sorry. I wasn't sure if any suggestions would be 'more general' and not leverage my CSS.

Comment: OK, without the full applications code this is useless too. But I think I've got the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I would use pure CSS for that:

```
<div id="controls">
 <div> "Separated" </div>
 <div> another control </div>
 <div> and one with an icon </div>
 ...
</div>
```

```css
#controls {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 10em; /* or whatever */
    /* implicit height: auto; */
    overflow: hidden; /* to hide the leftmost borders */
}
#controls > div {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 1em -1px; /* move the borders 1px into the off */
 }
```

This should give a scalable toolbar, and there is no need for different level-divs.